# Does a pokémon stay perfect when powering up?

Tags: pokemon-go

I've finally got enough candy to evolve magikarp to gyarados. I have a magikarp which when being apprised is said to be "incredible", which means it's close to perfect. It only has 143 cp though so I want to power this guy up before evolving to get a strong gyarados. But will the magikarp stay "perfect" being powered up?

Comment: Your concern right now is not really the "perfect" status, but whether the Gyarados would have good moves.  One with Hydro Pump will usually be better than one without.

Comment: Why power up before evolving? This seems like a bad idea...

Comment: as Boris pointed out. you really should not power up before evolving. the cost and effect of power up will be exactly the same whether you evolve first or after

Answer (score 12):

Yes IV's don't change when you power them up or even evolve them.

A 100% IV Pokemon will stay 100% no matter what you do to them.

Having a higher IV will mean that the CP cap is higher.